# Ubuntu 16.04 keyboard and touchpad does not react after suspend

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, suspend, xinput, mousepad

I got some very strange problems with my Laptop keyboard/mousepad...

I have two partitions on my SDD, one with Ubuntu 16.04 and the other one with Windows 10 (using GRUB as bootloader). Yesterday evening I put Ubuntu to suspend mode. Today I continue working on it - but it comes back with a strange behavior...

The mouse is jumping from the left bottom screen to the right top screen and executes randomly clicks.. The mousepad and keyboard does not reacting on input. I have to connect an external mouse and keyboard to perform input. But the mouse is still (annoying) jumping and clicking around. Then I try to see what xinput is saying - `xinput list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Gaming Mouse                 id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ WebCam SC-13HDN10939N                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Cherry GmbH wired keyboard                id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Cherry GmbH wired keyboard                id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Then I disabled the PS/2 Generic Mouse by `xinput --disable 16`.
Finally the random mouse moves stopped... (If I restart the system at this point, the moves come back...)

Then I tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all` to reinstall the drivers.
But with no success, keyboard and mouse still not reacting on input... Even on GRUB the keyboard does not working.

I do not know if this is important: An extern mouse was connected to the Laptop, before I put it to suspend. `Logitech USB Gaming Mouse`

What could be the problem?? Can anyone please help me...

**EDIT:**
Even on BIOS the laptop keyboard does not working. Only with an extern keyboard. But in the GRUB menu both keyboards does not working, so I can not even run windows again... How should the keyboard get destroyed?!

Comment: wow, weird. Have you tried rebooting into Ubuntu?

Comment: Sounds more like a hardware issue or at least a BIOS issue than a Ubuntu issue.  What motherboard does your laptop have, and what BIOS version are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have the solution (but not the reason) of the problem! (@Zanna - yes, 10 times or something like that and with that annoying mouse problem and no solution)
[Resetting the Motherboard](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=85363)

Take of battery pack (and disconnect from current source) for min. 5 minutes, then press the power button (without the battery or current source) for 30 seconds. Then put the battery pack back, press power -> it works now perfectly like the day before  .... halleluja